# How do I find week number of a date according to DATEFIRST

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to find week number of a `date` if start day is Tuesday and end day is Monday?

Here is the example criteria

```
      Date                          Output  
     ......                       ..........            
 01-Dec-2014 (Monday)   - 2014_DECEMBER_WEEK_NO_1 
 04-Dec-2014 (Thursday) - 2014_DECEMBER_WEEK_NO_1 
 29-Dec-2014 (Monday)   - 2014_DECEMBER_WEEK_NO_4 
 30-Dec-2014 (Tuesday)  - 2014_DECEMBER_WEEK_NO_5 
 31-Dec-2014 (Tuesday)  - 2014_DECEMBER_WEEK_NO_5
```

I tried following query:

```
select CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(YEAR, @FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_'+CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, @FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_WEEK_NO_'+CAST((DAY(@FROMDATE) 
+ (DATEPART(DW, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, @FROMDATE), 0))-1) -1)/7 + 1 AS VARCHAR(10))
```

This working fine if start day is Sunday and end day is Saturday.

Comment: Set first day of week and run the query again. Check this for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms181598.aspx

Comment: @Danish looks like useful information. But I need to change query in this case. Can you suggest query by using `DATEFIRST`

Comment: If start date is Sunday then week_no should return as 4 for today

Comment: Added an answer based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642870/calculate-all-sundays-mondays-saturdays-between-two-days-in-sql-server. Please let me know if it works/not works.

Comment: is the first day of the month and the next 6 days always considered week 1 of the month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your first day to `Tuesday`

```
SET DATEFIRST 2
```

Execute the following query

```
DECLARE @FROMDATE DATE='31-Dec-2014'

SELECT CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(YEAR, @FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_'+CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, @FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_WEEK_NO_'+REPLACE(CAST((DAY(@FROMDATE) 
+ (DATEPART(DW, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, @FROMDATE), 0))-1) -1)/7  AS VARCHAR(10)),'0','1')
```

**UPDATE**

```
SET DATEFIRST 2

DECLARE @FROMDATE DATE='12-JAN-2015'
DECLARE @ALLDATE DATE=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FROMDATE), 0)
DECLARE @FIRSTDATE DATE


; WITH  CTE as
 (
     SELECT 1 RNO,CAST(@ALLDATE AS DATE) as DATES 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT RNO+1, DATEADD(DAY,1,DATES )
     FROM    CTE
     WHERE   DATES < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@ALLDATE)
 )
 SELECT TOP 1 @FIRSTDATE =   DATES 
 FROM    CTE 
 WHERE DATEPART(W,DATES)=1


SELECT CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(YEAR, @FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_'+CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, @FROMDATE)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_WEEK_NO_'+CAST((DATEDIFF(DAY,@FIRSTDATE,@FROMDATE)/7)+1  AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: Run same query with input parameter `@FROMDATE` with `getdate()+2`, it gives output `2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_0` which is not correct.

Comment: What should be result for that date? @Ankush Madankar

Comment: `2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_1`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check @Ankush Madankar

Comment: Check with `getdate() + 8` it gives `2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_1` but week is second for that day (2015-01-07 Wend) i.e `2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_2`

Comment: Thats because 2015-01-07 Wend is the first Wend after first Tuesday of that month. And week2 will be the week for the days from 2nd Tuesday right?  @Ankush Madankar

Comment: I have added the UPDATE. Please check @Ankush Madankar

Comment: Working? @Ankush Madankar

Comment: Not working for `getdate()` as input parameter, output => `2014_DECEMBER_WEEK_NO_51`

Comment: Sorry for the interuption. I have updated in UPDATE. It will work now. Please check @Ankush Madankar

Comment: Working? @Ankush Madankar

Answer (score 1):

```
set datefirst 2 

DECLARE  @StartDate DATE = '2014-12-01',
         @EndDate   DATE = '2014-12-31',
         @DayCount int 


SELECT @DayCount = count(* )
FROM   (SELECT TOP ( datediff(DAY,@StartDate,@EndDate) + 1 )
                        [Date] = dateadd(DAY,ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER(ORDER BY c1.name),
                  DATEADD(DD,-1,@StartDate))
        FROM   [master].[dbo].[spt_values] c1 ) x
WHERE  datepart(dw,[Date]) = 1;


select CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(YEAR, @EndDate)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_'+CAST(UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, @EndDate)) AS VARCHAR(20))
+'_WEEK_NO_'+ Cast(@DayCount as varchar)
```

Comment: This wont work for 2 month i.e. `@StartDate = '2014-12-01' and @EndDate = '2015-01-01'` (`getdate() + 2`), gives result `2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_5`

Comment: You should give start date as the first date of the month as you want the answer as week_no_1. Anyway, what should be the answer according to you?

Comment: I don't know exact answer. I need this somewhere in report which shows weekly and monthly count of document. I am able to do for monthly and unable for weekly. Thanks for your response. Both  sarath and you. Now I think I need to find work-around!

Comment: What should be the 'WEEK_NO' for 1-DEC-2014?