# T-SQL - Determine number of specific days between 2 dates based on sales

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, datediff

**The Problem:**  Given a day of the week (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), a starting date and an ending date, compute the number of times the given day of the week appears between the starting and ending dates not inclusive of a date for which there were no sales.

**Context:**

Table "Ticket" has the following structure and sample content:

```
i_ticket_id c_items_total      dt_create_time       dt_close_time
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        8.50       '10/1/2012 10:23:00'    '10/1/2012 11:05:05'
2       10.50       '10/1/2012 11:00:00'    '10/1/2012 11:45:05'
3        8.50       '10/2/2012 08:00:00'    '10/2/2012 09:25:05'
4        8.50       '10/4/2012 08:00:00'    '10/4/2012 09:25:05'
5        7.50       '10/5/2012 13:22:23'    '10/5/2012 14:33:27'
.
.
233      6.75       '10/31/2012 23:20:00'   '10/31/2012 23:55:39'
```

**Details**

1. There may or may not be any tickets for one or more days during a month.  (i.e. the place was closed that/those day/s)
2. Days in which the business is closed are not regular.  There is no predictable pattern.

Based on [Get number of weekdays (Sundays, Mondays, Tuesdays) between two dates SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684577/get-number-of-weekdays-sundays-mondays-tuesdays-between-two-dates-sql), 
I have derived a query which returns the number of times a given day of the week occurs between the start date and the end date:

```
DECLARE @dtStart DATETIME = '10/1/2013 04:00:00'
DECLARE @dtEnd DATETIME = '11/1/2013 03:59:00'
DECLARE @day_number INTEGER = 1
DECLARE @numdays INTEGER

SET @numdays = (SELECT 1 + DATEDIFF(wk, @dtStart, @dtEnd)-
CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @dtStart)  @day_number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -
CASE WHEN DATEPART(weekday, @dtEnd) <= @day_number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Now I just need to filter this so that any zero-dollar days are not included in the count. Any help you can provide to add this filter based on the contents of the tickets table is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a calendar table to count the number of days where the day of week is n and between the start and end and is a date that has ticket sales, which I guess is when the date exists in tickets and has the `sum(c_items_total) > 0`

```
WITH cal AS 
(
  SELECT cast('2012-01-01' AS DATE) dt, datepart(weekday, '2012-01-01') dow
  UNION ALL      
  SELECT dateadd(day, 1, dt), datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, 1, dt))
  FROM cal
  WHERE dt < getdate()
)

SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM cal
WHERE dow = 5 
  AND dt BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-12-31'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tickets
    WHERE cast(dt_create_time AS DATE) = dt
    GROUP BY cast(dt_create_time AS DATE)
    HAVING sum(c_items_total) > 0
    )
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cb54/7)

Comment: This basically works.  I had to modify it slightly to take care of a couple edge cases but the premise is sound.  I'm going to mark as 'Answered' but will be interested to see if there are other approaches.